# Sigma algebra on smooth manifold

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function with $n > m$ and suppose $0$ is not a critical point. Then
$$
\mathcal{M} = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = 0\right\}
$$
is a smooth manifold by the preimage theorem. I am told that $\pi$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ but they don't specify the sigma-algebra.

> Given a smooth manifold, is there an obvious sigma algebra that one can always construct?

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is always defined.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thank you. Do you have any reference to this? or could you show me a proof?

Comment: It is defined for all $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff spaces. I think that Rudin's book discusses Borel sets in that generality.

Comment: The $\sigma$algebra om $\mathcal{M}$ might be than it inherits as a subspace of the Euclidean space $R^n$.